# How to backup bots OS X Server

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, xcode-server

Is there a way to backup bots on server app in OS X?

I have bots configured, and need to reinstall OS X on my machine. Is there a way to backup these bots (or maybe the entire server configuration), and then rebuild it from that backup?

Comment: Have you tried migrating the entire OS into the new machine?

Comment: Yes but i don't want to migrate entire OS, there is a lot of other stuff there that I simply do not want, and cleaning it one by one will be painful

Answer (score 2):

If you go to /Library/Developer/XcodeServer/ you'll find the location for all server assets. I would assume the bots are configured there as well, so if you change the permissions on these folders you should be able to access the bot configurations and copy them into the new machine. I haven't tried this myself but hopefully this works!

Comment: I have tried this and it worked moving from a Sierra machine to a different High Sierra machine. Note that the logged in user name needs to be the same between the two machines. Also each bot will need to select Edit Bot->Repositories->Replace Repositories->Update and then Sign In